# Solving nonlinear equations in octave with two unknowns

Tags: python, anaconda, octave, gnu, miniconda

I am trying to solve these two equations below in octave:
This is the code:

```
pkg load symbolic
syms x1 x2            
function f = fax(x)
  f(1) = -x(1) + 2*x(1)^3 + x(2);
  f(2) = -x(1) - x(2); 
 endfunction
 fsolve(@fax,[1,-1])
```

I get the answer as:

```
ans =

   1  -1
```

where it just displays the guess value.The fsolve doesn't solve the equations. How can I solve these equations?

Comment: Should it be x1 and x2 instead of x(1) and x(2)?